# Account enumeration on verification-less signup

Tags: email, user-enumeration

Is there a way to prevent account enumeration on signup page if access to the site is not requiring you to verify your email?

The scenario is as following:
Sign up for a site with email+password, but allow to use the site immediately. Some features require email validation, some don't, so the user can verify their email at a later stage.
When registering, if we deny another registration with email that exists in the system, we got account enumeration. If we let in, well, we just let anyone use any account without knowing a password.

Comment: Limit the requests for new accounts?

Comment: Sure, you just don't tie the user account to an email. That's pretty simple. Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @schroeder you mean like an username?

Comment: Yes, that's one method

Comment: yeah, but this brings me to starting point: when signing up i need to reveal which usernames are taken.

Comment: Not really, you can reveal what usernames are *possible*, being taken is just one possible reason.